# Gremlin: Return new edges created in a query without saving them (equivalent to APOC vRelationship)

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, janusgraph, amazon-neptune, neo4j-apoc

I have a graph with two types of nodes: Persons and Houses. In this graph, persons can sell houses (`SELLS` relationship), and houses are bought by persons (`IS_BOUGHT_BY` relationship). This could be represented as the following diagram:

```
(Person_1)-[:SELLS]->(House_1)-[:IS_BOUGHT_BY]->(Person_2)
```

A basic example of this diagram can be created in Neo4j by running:

```
CREATE(Person_1: Person {name:'Person 1'})
CREATE(House_1: House {name:'House 1', deal: 10238})
CREATE(Person_2: Person {name:'Person 2'})

CREATE
(Person_1)-[:SELLS]->(House_1),
(House_1)-[:IS_BOUGHT_BY]->(Person_2)
```

or can be created in Gremlin by executing:

```
g.
 addV('Person').property('name', 'Person 1').as('p1').
 addV('House').property('name', 'House 1').property('deal', 10238).as('h1').
 addV('Person').property('name', 'Person 1').as('p2').
 addE('SELLS').from('p1').to('h1').
 addE('IS_BOUGHT_BY').from('h1').to('p2')
```

I want to make a query that returns these Person nodes connected with a fake edge called `SELLS_HOUSE_TO` without saving this relationship in the database. Also this `SELLS_HOUSE_TO` relationship must have as deal property the deal id of the house sold by Person 1 and bought by Person 2. In other words, I want the output of the query to follow the following diagram:

```
(Person_1)-[:SELLS_HOUSE_TO {deal: house_1_deal}]->(Person_2)
```

where `id_deal` is the deal property of the `House_1` node, which connects `Person_1` and `Person_2` through the `SELLS` and `IS_BOUGHT_BY` relationships respectively.

This query can be easily done in Neo4j by using the `vRelationship` function provided by the APOC library:

```
MATCH (p1: Person)-[r1:SELLS]->(h1: House)-[r2:BUYS]->(p2: Person)
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(p1, 'SELLS_HOUSE_TO', {deal: h1.deal}, p2) YIELD rel
RETURN p1, rel, p2
```

It is possible to do something similar in Gremlin without involving storing the edges in the database at some step?

Comment: What sort of result would be acceptable from Gremlin? There is no way to create a virtual edge without resorting to something like a closure (which Neptune does not allow), but you could use a `project` step and return a map that looks a lot like a `path`. What do you intend to do with the result - is this for some sort of visualization you need to build?

Comment: Hello @Kelvin, thanks for your answer. Yes, the first thing I would want to do with that is to visualize it in Amazon Neptune. The second thing I would want to do is to save the query results to a file that would then allow me to easily import this new graph into Amazon Neptune or JanusGraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Gremlin, outside of perhaps using in-line code (closure/lambda), has no way to inject virtual edges into a query result. This might be a good feature request to open as a Jira ticket for Apache Tinkerpop at [this location](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TINKERPOP/issues/TINKERPOP-2424?filter=allopenissues).

As a short term solution, I think the best you can do is to create the edges for the needs of a visualization and perhaps give them a unique property key and value something like `"virtual":true` and to delete such edges when no longer needed.